# MaskedEditExtender for Date - Specifying minimum value

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am new to use the AJAX tool kit in ASP.NET

I have a masked edit extender for start date. How can I specify minimum date value on this?
Currently this is accepting 11/11/1111.

```
<asp:MaskedEditExtender runat="server" 
                        ID="meeStartDate" 
                        Mask="99/99/9999" 
                        MaskType="Date" 
                        TargetControlID="txtStartDate" />
```

I appreciate your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
MaximumValue="01/01/2099" MinimumValue="01/01/2000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
            this._minDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            this._maxDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(120);
```